# Url Rewriting Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite

```
http://xxx.tld/member/profile/PARAMETER
```

to

```
http://xxx.tld/PARAMETER
```

How is this done in Codeigniter?

Comment: By rewrite you mean redirect?

Comment: If the redirection is transparent , yes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but Codeigniter has routing and redirecting, not url rewriting. Rewriting feature almost always resides on the webserver like apache and nginx.

Comment: How i can proceed with an htaccess ?

Answer (score 2):

To rewrite use:

```
RewriteRule ^member/profile/PARAMETER$ /PARAMETER?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

To redirect use:

```
Redirect 301 http://xxx.tld/member/profile/PARAMETER http://xxx.tld/PARAMETER
```

or try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^member/profile/PARAMETER(.*)$ http://xxx.tld/PARAMETER$1 [r=301,nc]
```